# Javascript - var values not changed inside callback?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Why does changing the values of `status` and `output` inside the callback of a function I await for doesn't change their values outside?

```
var status = '';
var output = '';

if (orderTranscription != "TRANSCRIPTION_ERROR") {

    await runPython38Script ("processing.py", orderTranscription, (output) => {

        const orderInfo = JSON.parse(output);

        // Both of these have a value defined here when I console.log, not empty string
        status = orderInfo.status ? "VALID" : "PROCESSING_ERROR";
        output = orderInfo.output;
    });
}

// When I try to console.log outside, I get empty string.
console.log(status);
console.log(output);
```

Comment: Your `await` doesn't actually do anything here: `await`ing something that isn't a Promise (N.B. AFAIK it also *must* be a native Promise, not bluebird or q) is a no-op. If there isn't a promise-returning version of your function, then you'll have to wrap it in a Promise and resolve it in the callback.

Comment: are you sure ```if (orderTranscription != "TRANSCRIPTION_ERROR")``` match this condition..?

Comment: @JaredSmith "*AFAIK it also must be a native Promise, not bluebird or q*" [you can `await` any `.then()`-able](https://jsbin.com/juyagap/1/edit?js,console), not just native promises.

Comment: Might be relevant: [How do I convert an existing callback API to promises?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22519784)

Comment: @VLAZ I stand corrected.